# arrange two svg files on an html page

Tags: css, html, svg

I have two svg files, `1.svg` and `2.svg` that I want to arrange on an HTML page like so:

```
[1.svg]
[2.svg]
```

I want to set things up so that these are the only elements on the page, and that when you change the browser size, you get two different background colors behind each .svg that correspond to the svgs.

The way that I had set this up was to do two different divs:

```
<div class="top_body">
    <object data="images/1.svg" class="bg_top" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
<div class="bottom_body">
    <object data="images/2.svg" class="bg_bottom" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

and to style these as follows:

```
.bg-top {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.bg-bottom {
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}


.top_body {background-color:#{some color}  ;}
.bottom_body {background-color:#{some other color}  ;}
```

But there are two problems:

1. I want to make sure that the svg elements are centered, without whitespace on any side (right now there's whitespace on the left-hand side)
2. I want to make sure that the elements scale dynamically as the browser window changes size

I'm sure that this is a matter of tweaking my css, any pointers here?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question, the content on that page just explains how to embed svg files, not to work with them in the way that I'm describing.

Comment: You are using the SVG as an `object`. Try using it as an `<img>`.

Comment: as noted, I need to have access to parts of the svg to create a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-top {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.bg-bottom {
  width:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
}


.top_body {background-color:#{some color}  ;}
.bottom_body {background-color:#{some other color}  ;}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by:
(a) make sure your SVGs have a valid "viewBox" attribute
(b) Set the "width" and "height" attributes in the SVG to "100%"
(c) Add or set the "preserveAspectRatio" attribute on the SVG to "xMidYMid slice"

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" ...etc...>
```

The actual values of viewBox will depend on your SVG file

Answer (score 0):

So let's break this up in to 3 different criteria:

**1.) I want to make sure that the svg elements are centered, without whitespace on any side (right now there's whitespace on the left-hand side)**

To make sure an SVG element is centered we will need to make sure that the coordinates are set up correctly for any paths inside of the SVG, and that the ViewBox (if we need one) is configured with the correct starting coordinates. In the below example I have an SVG with coordinates 0,0 to 200,100. The paths inside these are rectangles starting at 0 and going 200 along, and 0 going to 100. If your SVGs paths aren't starting at the correct coordinates the whitespace is being added by design.

I have included preserveAspectRatio="none" as this will allow the SVG to scale at uneven ratios. The height and width of the browser may not allow for nice scaling, and this will mean whitespace will start to appear. This allows the SVG to grow at different ratios. The default option is that the SVG will grow uniformly in both axis and fill with white space if unable to in the axis that grew the larger amount to make up the difference.

**2.) I want to make sure that the elements scale dynamically as the browser window changes size**

To scale dynamically, for the width we can just use 100% width, and the SVGs will always be taking up the entire width of it's parent, in this case the BODY element.

To scale with height we have a bit more trouble as 100% height is potentially more than on screen. To fix this we can use the Viewport Height, so that the element takes up only 100% of the onscreen realestate. To do this we use

> height="100vh"

If we stick this on both elements, each will now be the size of the view port and will scale when the view port scales.

**3.) When you change the browser size, you get two different background colors behind each .svg**

To do this we can use media queries. We can set different queries that, when met, we can change the styling behind the SVG.

To test this, you will have to resize your browser for the example so that you can meet each media query.

```css
#svg1, #svg2{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#svg1{
  fill: red;
}

#svg2{
  fill: blue;
}

@media (min-height: 50px) {  
  #svg1{
    fill: green;
  }

  #svg2{
    fill: yellow;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 150px) {  
  #svg1{
    fill: pink;
  }

  #svg2{
    fill: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 100"
      id="svg1"
      preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="200" height="100" />
</svg>
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 100"
    id="svg2"
    preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="200" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Hope this helps!